# Single submit button should perform multiple actions in php

Tags: php, html

I have two php pages.

1. dataentryform.php
2. report.php

In dataentryform.php through form tag I'm taking 19 user inputs with `fcode` being a primary key. Upon submit I want two things to happen.

1. data stored into the database
2. the data entered in the form should get displayed on the report.php
   file.

My Problem:

1. Able to store values into the database and also retrieve it.
2. But, the values printed on the report.php file will always
   correspond to the first row in the table

How do I fix this?

**dataentryform.php**

```
<form method="post" action="includes/dbinsert.php">
        <table width="650" border="1" class="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Farmer's Code</td>
      <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="fcode" 
class="text" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Farmer Name</td>
      <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="fname" 
class="text" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Village/ Town</td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="village" class="text" 
autocomplete="off" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Survey Number</td>
      <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="surnum" 
class="text" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Plot Number</td>
      <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="plotnum" 
class="text" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    </tr>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Potash (Tons/Acre)</td>
      <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="number" name="potash" 
class="range" min="0" step="0.001" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**dbinsert.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$fcode = $_POST['fcode'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$village = $_POST['village'];
$surnum = $_POST['surnum'];
$plotnum = $_POST['plotnum'];
$acre = $_POST['acre'];
$gunta = $_POST['gunta'];
$soiltype = $_POST['soiltype'];
$wtrsrc = $_POST['wtrsrc'];
$factory = $_POST['factory'];
$labnum = $_POST['labnum'];
$nextcrop = $_POST['nextcrop'];
$coldate = $_POST['coldate'];
$gendate = $_POST['gendate'];
$season = $_POST['season'];
$taryield = $_POST['taryield'];
$nitro = $_POST['nitro'];
$phos = $_POST['phos'];
$potash = $_POST['potash'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO forminfo (fcode,fname,village,surnum,plotnum,acre,gunta,soiltype,wtrsrc,factory,labnum,
                               nextcrop,coldate,gendate,season,taryield,nitro,phos,potash)
        VALUES ('$fcode','$fname','$village','$surnum','$plotnum','$acre','$gunta','$soiltype','$wtrsrc','$factory','$labnum',
                 '$nextcrop','$coldate','$gendate','$season','$taryield','$nitro','$phos','$potash');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header('location:../report.php');
?>
```

dbinsert.php is inserting values into the database. Then redirecting to report.php. Here I'm including dbextract.php. However, values displayed in report.php are incorrect.
Tried with this also but no luck.

**dbextract.php**

```
 <?php
      include 'dbconnect.php';
      $fcode = $_POST['fcode'];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM forminfo WHERE fcode=['$fcode']";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
 ?>
```

> Error: Unidentified variable `$fcode`.

Comment: Want to extract only the row corresponding to "fcode"(primary key) and print it in report.php

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['fcode']);` inside your `dbextract.php` should give you some very interesting results. Like `$_POST['fcode']` being undefined

Comment: Throwing error- Notice: Undefined index: fcode. How do I get variable fcode from dataentryform.php into dbextract.php ? probably this might help me.

Comment: I wolud like to also poin out that there are several other undefined Indexes in `dbinsert.php`. The $_POST data you are trying to get does not correspond with the data you are sending through the form, according to the code you provided. I would advise checkin if php errors are turned on and adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` to each of your php files at the very beginning just to be sure t6hat errors are showing. You can also be getting the `Cannot modify header information` warning.

Comment: No such warning

Comment: how are you redirecting to `dbextract.php`.?

Answer (score 0):

You could use session variables by adding

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST;
```

at the beginning of `dbinsert.php` and then using `$fcode = $_SESSION['data']['fcode'];` on `dbextract.php`

Comment: Saving full post data to session is a bit of an overkill, considering only one single value is needed. But it will work.

Comment: Is there a way to send form data to multiple php files ?

Answer (score 0):

To claryfy Twista's answer - The Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example would probably look like the example below.

**NOTE:**

*I pretty much excluded everything that was causing any sort of errors, i also omitted the actual database insertion, since it doesn't really relate to the problem.*

Judging by provided code the was actually one big problem:

Undefined indexes. Judging by provided code **dbinsert.php** has a lot of them. `$acre = $_POST['acre']` and every  `$_POST[]` after it should yeild `Warning: Undefined index`.

**dbextract.php** also has a very invalid SQL Query. It probably should have  being `SELECT * FROM forminfo WHERE fcode='$fcode'`.

Actually  it would be better if you used [MySQLi Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

The example below demonstrates working with `$_SESSION`.

**dataentryform.php**

```
<form method="post" action="dbinsert.php">
  <table width="650" border="1" class="table1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Farmer's Code</td>
        <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="fcode" class="text" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Farmer Name</td>
        <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="fname" class="text" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Village/ Town</td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="village" class="text" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Survey Number</td>
        <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="surnum" class="text" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Plot Number</td>
        <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="plotnum" class="text" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      </tr>
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Potash (Tons/Acre)</td>
        <td width="350" colspan="2"><input type="number" name="potash" class="range" min="0" step="0.001" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**dbinsert.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // include 'dbconnect.php';
  $fcode = $_POST['fcode'];
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $village = $_POST['village'];
  $surnum = $_POST['surnum'];
  $plotnum = $_POST['plotnum'];

  $_SESSION['fcode']=$fcode;

  // $sql = "INSERT INTO forminfo (fcode,fname,village,surnum,plotnum,acre,gunta,soiltype,wtrsrc,factory,labnum,
                                 // nextcrop,coldate,gendate,season,taryield,nitro,phos,potash)
          // VALUES ('$fcode','$fname','$village','$surnum','$plotnum','$acre','$gunta','$soiltype','$wtrsrc','$factory','$labnum',
                   // '$nextcrop','$coldate','$gendate','$season','$taryield','$nitro','$phos','$potash');";
  // mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  header('location: dbextract.php');
?>
```

**dbextract.php**

```
<?php
  //session_start();
  // include 'dbconnect.php';
  $fcode = $_SESSION['fcode'];
  //$fcode = $_GET['fcode'];
  var_dump($fcode);
  // $sql = "SELECT * FROM forminfo WHERE fcode=['$fcode']";
  // $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  // $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
?>
```

The same can be done without the use of `$_SESSION`. **dataentryform.php** stays the same.

**dbinsert.php**

```
<?php
  //session_start();
  // include 'dbconnect.php';
  $fcode = $_POST['fcode'];
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $village = $_POST['village'];
  $surnum = $_POST['surnum'];
  $plotnum = $_POST['plotnum'];

  //$_SESSION['fcode']=$fcode;

  // $sql = "INSERT INTO forminfo (fcode,fname,village,surnum,plotnum,acre,gunta,soiltype,wtrsrc,factory,labnum,
                                 // nextcrop,coldate,gendate,season,taryield,nitro,phos,potash)
          // VALUES ('$fcode','$fname','$village','$surnum','$plotnum','$acre','$gunta','$soiltype','$wtrsrc','$factory','$labnum',
                   // '$nextcrop','$coldate','$gendate','$season','$taryield','$nitro','$phos','$potash');";
  // mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  header('location: dbextract.php/?fcode='.$fcode);
?>
```

**dbextract.php**

```
<?php
  //session_start();
  // include 'dbconnect.php';
  //$fcode = $_SESSION['fcode'];
  $fcode = $_GET['fcode'];
  var_dump($fcode);
  // $sql = "SELECT * FROM forminfo WHERE fcode=['$fcode']";
  // $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  // $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
?>
```

The above shows that it can be done without `$_SESSION`. The thing that happens in this exaple is that you pass your desired value as a param. Then the `GET` request happens, and then you use `$_GET['fcode']` to get your value.

**!!!IMPORTANT!!!**

The exapmles above, are just that - examples. You will likely have to customise them a bit to suit your needs. For instance - you will have to actually un-comment parts, that are working with database and re-write them a bit.

Consearning sending data with a single `POST` request to several different `.php` files - On the server side as far as i am aware a **single** `POST` request sends data to a **single** file. ***Note*** it is possible to send several POST request using AJAX, but AJAX works on client side, so AJAX won't be of assistance if a redirect happens at server side.

Comment: This helped me with slight modifications. Thank you